# MVC4 Child application needs to override assembly in parent application web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, assemblies

I am working on integrating SSRS reports into an application. This MVC application is nested within a parent application which is all webforms. The assembly I need is conflicting with the version in the parent web config and I need to override it in the child. I cannot break inheritance in the parent because there are dependent files at the top level of the application. Any way I can ignore it in child web config? I tried to remove the assembly in the compilation section like below but that didn't work:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1">
   <assemblies>
      <remove assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
   </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since my parent application is a webforms app, I decided to create a webforms application just to run SSRS reports that way I can inherit the assemblies. I cannot break the inheritance at the top level web config because other modules adopt them. Not the best solution but it will work for what I need. 
JUST Fyi- the binding redirect did not override the parent assembly.